# How to handle dynamically changing ID's on refresh?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to handle dynamically changing ID's on refresh?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's very common question but i would like to answer this question.

If id's are dynamic the  you can go with any other locator techniques which ever is suitable in case of your app. 
e.g. Name , className.

Mostly use of advance css or Xpath should work in your case. but you need to find unique set of properties / attribute values to locate.

Keep this in mind - just ignore on the part which is changing...focus on the part which is not changing and try to use that in any locator you choose.

Comment: ok thanks a lot...great...